# How to convert QtCreator project to Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, project, qt-creator, project-conversion

I have a QtCreator project file *.pro

How to convert it to Visual Studio 2008 project *.sln?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can also use the qmake command to do this.
Go to the project dir and type "qmake -tp vc".

Answer (score 6):

Qt Creator / qmake can generate `*.vcproj*` files directly.

> Put "TEMPLATE=vcapp" or "TEMPLATE=vclib" (as appropriate) in your .pro
> file and run qmake. That will generate a .vcproj file.

Answer (score 6):

It's now possible to open the .pro file directly from the [Qt Visual Studio Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2022) extension. Visual Studio will then generate the necessary solution files. Currently the extension is available for [VS2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools), [VS2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2015), [VS2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools-19123), [VS2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2019) and [VS2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2022).

> **Step 1. Install the QT Visual Studio Extension.** From the Marketplace,
> install the [Qt Visual Studio Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2022) extension.
>
> **Step 2. Import your .pro projects into Visual Studio.** To do that,
> select the **Qt VS Tools > Open Qt Project File (.pro)** to let the
> extension create a VS solution and project from your existing Qt .pro
> file. More information on this is available in the Qt docs covering [Qt
> project management in Visual Studio](http://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/qtvstools-managing-projects.html#importing-and-exporting-projects).

Answer copied from this blog post: [Bring your existing Qt projects to Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/14/bring-your-existing-qt-projects-to-visual-studio/).